# Compute the expectation of the maximum of conditioned variables

Tags: probability

Let $X_1,X_2\sim U(0,10)$ be two i.i.d. continious random variables.

Compute:
$E[\max(X_1,Y-X_1,10-Y)]$, where $Y= X_2|X_1\le X_2$

Comment: Since $T(X_1,X_2) \neq T(X_2,X_1)$, I'm not sure you can make that 'WLOG' statement.

Comment: Well, then we have 3 different cases: 1.) $X_1\lt X_2$ with probability $\frac 12$ 2.) $X_1\gt X_2$ with probability $\frac 12$ and 3.) $X_1= X_2$ with probability $0$

Comment: If you make a change of variable: $Y = 10 - X_2$ then you have a symmetric $T = 20 - 2E[\max(X,Y,10-(X+Y)]$. Notice that $Y = 10 - X_2 \sim U(0,10)$

Comment: It's possible that the original problem statement is symmetric, just not apparent. Your WLOG statement may be valid, but is more comfortably used after the transformation

Comment: You state that $Y = 10-X_2\sim U(0,10)$, but in this case, $X_2$ is conditioned on $X_1$ ain't it? So $X_2|X_1\le X_2 \not{\sim}U(0,10)$

Comment: It was never stated that $X_2$ is conditioned on $X_1$. I'm considering them independent. Wait, is $T$ always as stated? Or is it conditional on $X_1 \leq X_2$

Comment: Sorry, my mistake. I meant in the beginning that T is conditional on $X_1 \le X_2$.

Comment: If it wasn't, would $T = \max(X, \max(X-Y), 10 - (X+Y))$?

Comment: I tried to clarify my question above, because I get the feeling we don't understand each other ;)

Comment: "and $Y= X_2|X_1\le X_2$" What is the meaning of $Y= X_2|X_1\le X_2$? Please be specific. It seems $Y$ should be a random variable, on which probability space is it defined, and what is $Y(\omega)$ for $\omega$ in this probability space?

Comment: Not an answer, but a lot of theorems about the distribution of max fall under "extreme value theory"